# Constantinople fork replay protection

Tags: hardforks, replay-attack, constantinople

I was wondering...

Will Constantinople hard fork surely replace the current fork?

Is there any chance that the Constantinople fork and the current one will co-exist?

If so, any replay attack protection was designed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there has been no major talk about anyone sustaining the pre-Constantinople fork after the fork block. Also there has been no replay protection AFAIK from pre to post Constantinople